# Shouldn't [software-recommendations] be [software-recommendation]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Shouldn't [hardware-recommendation](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hardware-recommendation) and [software-recommendations](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-recommendations) both have the plural "s" or not?

I think it makes more sense for them to both be singular, since each question should be limited to one topic of recommendation per question. But the case could also be made that questions using these tags are seeking multiple different recommendations for *answers* in some cases, so it's not a big deal if they both have the plural "s". Either way, it annoys me that they are different :P

Comment: Maybe both singular with a plural synonym?

Comment: There's not really a point in a synonym that's one additional letter since all users adding the tag will have the correct (non-plural) tag suggested

Comment: that is true /*filler to get to the minimum content required*/

Comment: +1 for both singular

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I renamed `software-recommendations` to `software-recommendation` — DONE.

A synonym isn't necessary here. Synonyms were intended to link two completely separate words meaning essentially the same thing (think 'car' vs 'auto'). For simple variations on the *same* word, text completion will help guide the user to the correct usage.

<kbd>s</kbd><kbd>o</kbd><kbd>f</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> → <kbd>software-recommendation</kbd>

There's no need to bulk up the tag listings with every word inflection.